# `ggplot` - overlay bar chart from different `data.frames` - one in long format the other not

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I am working with two `data frames`. In `data1` there are 3 stock symbols, `AAPL` , `GOOG`and `NFLX` in `data2` there is another benchmark index, say the `S&P500`.

I have the following code which I am using a package called `tidyquant`:

```
Ra_annual_returns %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = yearly.returns, fill = symbol)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = palette_light()[[1]]) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "FB, AMZN, NFLX, GOOG Annual Returns",
       subtitle = "Get annual returns quickly with tq_transmute",
       y = "Annual Returns", x = "") +
  facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2) +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_fill_tq()
```

What I am trying to do is to overlay the yearly `data2` bar_chart onto the current `ggplot` I have, so I can see the difference between the stock returns against the benchmark but I am having trouble since `data1` is in long format and `data2` is not.

Data1:

```
Ra_annual_returns <- structure(list(symbol = c("AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
"AAPL", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "NFLX", 
"NFLX", "NFLX", "NFLX", "NFLX", "NFLX"), date = structure(c(14974, 
15338, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16595, 14974, 15338, 15705, 16070, 
16435, 16595, 14974, 15338, 15705, 16070, 16435, 16595), class = "Date"), 
    yearly.returns = c(0.507219845299458, 0.255580319466791, 
    0.399062561777016, 0.258354130986155, 0.509186792546526, 
    0.163772585970537, -0.0523015585522321, 0.0874286460637179, 
    0.0951849907027951, 0.584311213430311, -0.059656111290302, 
    0.00605243426685909, 2.28534031413613, -0.605634621513944, 
    0.336267932007559, 2.97634734878121, -0.0721405726683247, 
    0.894411639167131)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("symbol", "date", 
"yearly.returns"), vars = "symbol", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:5, 6:11, 12:17), group_sizes = c(6L, 6L, 6L), biggest_group_size = 6L, labels = structure(list(
    symbol = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "NFLX")), row.names = c(NA, -3L
), class = "data.frame", vars = "symbol", drop = TRUE, .Names = "symbol"))
```

Data 2:

```
Rb_annual_returns <- structure(list(date = structure(c(14974, 15338, 15705, 16070, 
16435, 16595), class = "Date"), yearly.returns = c(0.0976698601525789, 
0.0261384119933952, 0.152962677798244, 0.262436498950858, 0.178441518781995, 
0.0288720123502142)), .Names = c("date", "yearly.returns"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT: I have the data in the following format: So I am trying to plot `yearly.returns.x` and overlay `yearly.returns.y` using `facet_wrap` symbol.

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   symbol [?]
   symbol date       yearly.returns.x yearly.returns.y
   <chr>  <date>                <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 FB     2013-12-31           0.952            0.222 
 2 FB     2014-12-31           0.428            0.178 
 3 FB     2015-12-31           0.341            0.0547
 4 FB     2016-12-30           0.0993           0.150 
 5 AMZN   2013-12-31           0.550            0.222 
 6 AMZN   2014-12-31          -0.222            0.178 
 7 AMZN   2015-12-31           1.18             0.0547
 8 AMZN   2016-12-30           0.109            0.150 
 9 NFLX   2013-12-31           3.00             0.222 
10 NFLX   2014-12-31          -0.0721           0.178 
11 NFLX   2015-12-31           1.34             0.0547
12 NFLX   2016-12-30           0.0824           0.150 
13 GOOG   2013-12-31           0.550            0.222 
14 GOOG   2014-12-31          -0.0597           0.178 
15 GOOG   2015-12-31           0.450            0.0547
16 GOOG   2016-12-30           0.0171           0.150
```

Data:

```
RaRb <- structure(list(symbol = c("FB", "FB", "FB", "FB", "AMZN", "AMZN", 
"AMZN", "AMZN", "NFLX", "NFLX", "NFLX", "NFLX", "GOOG", "GOOG", 
"GOOG", "GOOG"), date = structure(c(16070, 16435, 16800, 17165, 
16070, 16435, 16800, 17165, 16070, 16435, 16800, 17165, 16070, 
16435, 16800, 17165), class = "Date"), yearly.returns.x = c(0.951785785714286, 
0.427630267973275, 0.34145101287302, 0.0992738257491372, 0.549842649332266, 
-0.221770859359719, 1.17783148681492, 0.109455648638337, 3.00141285726741, 
-0.0721405726683247, 1.34378371699354, 0.082357110046086, 0.549547256602323, 
-0.059656111290302, 0.449568196562607, 0.0170514467567242), yearly.returns.y = c(0.22178112867623, 
0.178441518781995, 0.0547092831470988, 0.150127297343264, 0.22178112867623, 
0.178441518781995, 0.0547092831470988, 0.150127297343264, 0.22178112867623, 
0.178441518781995, 0.0547092831470988, 0.150127297343264, 0.22178112867623, 
0.178441518781995, 0.0547092831470988, 0.150127297343264)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), .Names = c("symbol", 
"date", "yearly.returns.x", "yearly.returns.y"), vars = "symbol")
```

Comment: So the problem is really just how to do wide to long with a tibble?

Comment: That gets me thinking, maybe I will add to my original post with another plot I would like to make also.

Comment: `ggplot` expects data in long format. You'll have a much easier time if you convert the second data frame to a long shape. There are a lot of SO posts on doing that, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format?rq=1. If that's the issue, I'd say this isn't really a `ggplot` question

Comment: Well I joined the data frames by: `RaRb <- left_join(Ra_annual_returns, Rb_annual_returns, by = c("date" = "date"))
`

Comment: Now just need to overlay two columns

Comment: Then applying `RaRb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, fill = symbol)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = yearly.returns.x), (stat = "identity")) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = yearly.returns.y), (stat = "identity")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = palette_light()[[1]]) +
  facet_wrap(~ symbol, ncol = 2) +
  theme_tq() +
  scale_fill_tq()` Gives me an error: `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character`